# How to flatten nested objects in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to flatten the following object 'raw' into object 'flat'

```
raw = [    {
      "id":"123",
      "Date":"12/12/2020",
      "Type":{
         "id":"456",
         "desc":"test1"
      }    },    {
      "id":"124",
      "Date":"12/12/2020",
      "Type":{
         "id":"456",
         "desc":"test2"
      }    } ]
```

```
flat =[   {
      "id":"123",
      "Date":"12/12/2020",
      "desc":"test1"
      },    
      {
      "id":"124",
      "Date":"12/12/2020",
      "desc":"test2"
      }]
```

I attempted the following:

```
   let flatData:any = []
    const flattenObject = (obj:any) => {
      const flattened:any = {}
    
      Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
        if (typeof obj[key] === 'object' && obj[key] !== null) {
          Object.assign(flattened, flattenObject(obj[key]))
        } else {
          flattened[key] = obj[key]
        }
      })
      flatData.push(flattened)
      console.log(flattened)
      return flattened
    }
```

Result I get from the code snippet above.

[image]

...........................................................................................

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [object destructuring](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/future-javascript/destructuring) in TypeScript.

```js
const raw = [{
  "id": "123",
  "Date": "12/12/2020",
  "Type": {  "id": "456",  "desc": "test1" }
}, {
  "id": "124",
  "Date": "12/12/2020",
  "Type": {  "id": "456", "desc": "test2" }
}];

const mapped = raw.map(({ id, Date, Type: { desc } }) => ({ id, Date, desc }));

console.log(mapped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The function you are using to flatten the object is correct, however, the nested `id` property in the `Type` property has the same property name as the top-level `id` property. When you flatten the object, that top-level `id` value is overwritten with the nested `id` value.

**Solutions**:

1. If you have control of the data, you could rename the nested `id` property to something else.
2. In the `flattenObject` function, you could prefix the nested property with the parent property name. i.e.

```
const flattenObject = (obj:any, prefix = '') => {
      const flattened:any = {}
    
      Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
        if (typeof obj[key] === 'object' && obj[key] !== null) {
          Object.assign(flattened, flattenObject(obj[key], prefix))
        } else {
          flattened[prefix + key] = obj[key]
        }
      })
      flatData.push(flattened)
      return flattened
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works in case you have only one depth level and if you want to flatten objects, no matter what's the property name:

```js
const raw = [
  {
    id: "123",
    Date: "12/12/2020",
    Type: {
      id: "456",
      desc: "test1",
    },
  },
  {
    id: "124",
    Date: "12/12/2020",
    Type: {
      id: "456",
      desc: "test2",
    },
  },
];

const flatten = (obj) =>
  Object.assign(
    {},
    Object.fromEntries(
      Object.values(obj)
        .filter((x) => typeof x === "object")
        .map((x) => Object.entries(x))
        .flat(1)
    ),
    Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(obj).filter(([, x]) => typeof x !== "object")
    )
  );

const compute = (data) => data.map(flatten);

console.log(compute(raw));
```

Comment: The top-level `id` value is overwritten with the nested `id` value.